# Why is ColorFunction called more than once for every color cell

Tags: graphics, color

I was trying to use a custom `ColorFunction` with `Raster` and I noticed it gets called seemingly a random number of times for each colour cell.

```
i=0; 
mycolourfn[a_] := (
i++; Print[i, a];
RGBColor@Append[Take[RotateLeft[a], 3], Last[a]]);

Graphics[Raster[{
{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}}, 
{{1, 0, 0, 0.5}, {0, 1, 0, 0.5}, {0, 0, 1, 0.5}}}, 
ColorFunction -> mycolourfn]]
```

> 1{1.,0.,0.,1.} 2{1.,0.,0.,1.} .... 20{0,1,0,0.5} 21{0,0,1,0.5}

So here `mycolourfn` gets called 21 times while there are only 6 colour cells and also a different number of times per colour cell. It seems completely random how many times `mycolourfn` gets called if you change the number of colour cells.

What I wanted to do was create a `ColorFunction` with a variable like `i` here, to keep track of what cell it was on and do something slightly different based on where it was. Of course, that didn't quite work out properly. I realised a short while later that this sort of modification is probably best done on the data itself and then passing that to `Raster` instead of messing around with `ColorFunction`.

But I'm still curious. Why is it not called the same number of times as there are colour cells?

Comment: It seems to use 3 or 4 calls per box. Maybe it needs to know the color at the start/end of each box it draws, and so makes calls to ensure that the color hasn't changed.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense as even with just one colour cell 6 calls are used.